Flutter and IOS images not showing
Having an issue with a Flutter application when running on IOS, some of the images refuse to display. This only seems to affect release versions.
I see no errors in any logs during debugging, or when running the flutter command:
flutter run --release
This doesn't affect the Android version at all from what I can see.
All images are stored under assets/images
Typical usage:
 image: AssetImage(Constant.assetImagePath + imagePath),

Could you provide the values of “ Constant.assetImagePath” and “imagePath”

assetImagePath = "assets/images/"
imagePath is dependant on user input but an example would be: "testImage.png"

Okay thank you, and to confirm you have the image defined in the assets section of the pubspec.yaml?

I currently have this in the yaml file :
assets:
- assets/images/
All of my images are in contained in that folder
